# How to show string output in console.log with quotation marks?

Tags: javascript, console.log

The problem is if I console log this string: `"Lorem "` the `console.log` will output: `Lorem` and I can't tell if at the end of the string there is white space or not.

How can I force console to show output in quotation marks?

Comment: `console.log('"Lorem "');`

Comment: You cannot really do that. You can just add delimiters and potentially overwrite the `console.log` to always do that. But it's probably too much of a hack to do for the whole application.

Comment: Use another console.

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify("Lorem "))

Comment: It actually prints with the space, it is just we don't see that. If you try highlighting the printed string you will see spaces getting selected.

Comment: If you're concerned about the whitespace you could also do something like `console.log(varName === varName.trim());`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```js
let s = "Lorem";
console.log( JSON.stringify(s) );
```

Comment: I was afraid that this is the only best solution (which is the most readable) I think. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
let lorem = "Lorem ";
console.log('"'+lorem+'"');
// Prints: "Lorem "
```

More generally, the pattern `console.log('"'+expression+'"')` will print out the expression with quotes on either side so you can see where the actual beginning and end of the expression is.

If you want this to happen every time, consider creating a function like so:

```
function myConsole(...expr){
  console.log('"'+expr.join(' ')+'"');
}
```

And using that instead of console.log

Comment: If you remove `...` and `.join(' ')` it will works too :)

Comment: It will for any unary call, but `console.log` is technically variadic, so someone expecting `myConsole` to work like `console.log` might reasonably attempt `myConsole(anExpression, anotherExpression, aThirdExpression)`, which wouldn't work without the `...`. The `.join(' ')` is unnecessary except that it separates the arguments with a space.

Answer (score 3):

Simply escape the slashes:

```js
console.log("\"Lorem \"")
```

or wrap the double quotes in single quotes (or vice-verse)

```js
console.log('"Lorem "');
```

Answer (score 1):

To show single quote ( " ) with a string use this syntax

```
console.log("\"\Your string");
```

gives output as **"Your string**